# OpenJPA - not flushing before queries

Tags: java, persistence, openjpa

how can i set openjpa to flush before query. When i change some values in database i want to propagate these changes into application.

I tried this settings in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="openjpa.FlushBeforeQueries" value="true" />
<property name="openjpa.IgnoreChanges" value="false"/> false/true - same behavior to my case
<property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="false"/>
<property name="openjpa.RemoteCommitProvider" value="sjvm"/>
<property name="openjpa.ConnectionRetainMode" value="always"/>
<property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="false"/>
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling refresh() on an object inside trasaction does the trick :)